# How to add new portals on FileMaker pro?

Tags: filemaker

I'm very new to FileMaker Pro and I want to know if it's possible to add new portals for every time I select a new value from a value list drop down menu?

For example
On a text field, if I select a value from the drop down menu, a new portal shows up. If I select another value from the drop down menu, I want a another portal to show up.

Is this possible using FileMaker pro?
Is this even a valid question?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: "*Is this possible using FileMaker pro? Is this even a valid question?*" Not really, to both. Why don't you explain **what** you want to accomplish, instead of **how** you think it needs to accomplished. -- Note also that selecting a value from a drop-down menu **replaces** the previously selected value. So the user expectation would be for something to **change** - not for something new to **appear**. And where would you put all those new portals popping up? And what would make them go away?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Because I am trying to make a school attendance file. The teacher will create a class from a layout, then they will go to the attendance layout, select the class that they made and they can record student names on the portal that is given. If the teacher creates a different class, how can I make a different portal for that other class that the teacher made?

Comment: IMHO, if a teacher selects another class, then the **existing** portal (or list layout) should show the attendance for the newly selected class. -- P.S. Not to discourage you, but this is not really a beginner-level project.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I am aware that this is not an easy task but is there something you can make me refer to or something that would help?

Comment: I am afraid this may be too broad for SO. This is not just a matter of selecting a class and firing away; you need to have the correct structure of tables (Courses, Students, Enrollments, Classes and Attendance as a minimum) and relationships in place before you can build the UI for taking attendance. Let me suggest you join one of Filemaker forums, e.g. http://fmforums.com/, https://fmdev.filemaker.com/, http://forums.filemaker.com/ or http://forums.filemaker.com/ where you can discuss this in more detail, including posting files (at least on some of them) as necessary.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Okay, thank you for your help. I appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 2):

I'm in the dark on your design but this can be done by adding a script trigger to the field that the drop-down list is attached to and then placing the portals in a tab set.

This way when you select the appropriate value it will switch to the tab with the corresponding portals.

Comment: Another cleaner more dynamic option is to make the classname and the teacher name match fields for the portal.  But I don't know how far along you are in your understanding of relational structure.